# How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, directory

How do I get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?

The only thing I could find was the VB.NET-only class [`SpecialDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0be29hd.aspx), which has this property:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
```

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 950, accepted):

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Comment: The items returned from this folder is different to what Window Explorer shows. E.g. in my XP, it doesn't include My Documents, My Computer, My Network Places, Recycle Bin and some other shortcuts. Any idea how to get the same entries as Windows Explorer?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory? This is the physical folder instead of the logical.

Comment: This returns me the admin user desktop if the program is run as admin

Comment: btw this class is in the System namespace (as in System.Environment)

Answer (score 39):

```
// Environment.GetFolderPath
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); // Current User's Application Data
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData); // All User's Application Data
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles); // Program Files
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies); // Internet Cookie
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); // Logical Desktop
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory); // Physical Desktop
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites); // Favorites
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.History); // Internet History
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache); // Internet Cache
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer); // "My Computer" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); // "My Documents" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic); // "My Music" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures); // "My Pictures" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // "My Document" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles); // Program files Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs); // Programs Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent); // Recent Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo); // "Sent to" Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu); // Start Menu
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup); // Startup
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System); // System Folder
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates); // Document Templates
```