# What guaranteed file writing locations are available?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

On the local system, is there a (reasonably) guaranteed place to create a directory structure to write files? I'm looking for a solution that does not require Administrative Privileges for permission changes?

After a bit of research, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c) answer for finding the current user's desktop folder. I *could* use this, but what other options are available?

***Putting together research***:

[`System.Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) Enumeration

Comment: The executing directory is always guaranteed.

Comment: Really?  The executing application can always write to the directory it is started in?  Can you provide a reference?  I don't believe that is true (remember with Vista, programs that were used to writing to folders under their installation location no longer functioned unless granted elevated privileges, or if UAC was disabled).

Comment: I was amusing only read permissions not write (guess I missed it in the question). Yes of course you are correct if wanting write permissions.

Comment: @EricJ.: In Vista, programs that were used to writing folders under their installation location usually still functioned even if not granted elevated privileges.  However, this was due to a compatibility shim which caused the read/write operations to be redirected to a different folder.  Of course, this has all sorts of weird side effects (e.g., running a legacy program as admin gives it a completely different set of settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special folders are, in fact, special because there is a reasonable guarantee that they will be present.

No other folders have such a guarantee.  Even `C:\` is not guaranteed (though it is quite likely to be present on the vast majority of Windows systems).

A custom folder under [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) is a common place to write application specific data for a given user or `CommonApplicationData` for application data to be shared across all users on the system..

In environments where roaming is implemented (the user's data comes with him, no matter which physical server he logs onto), `ApplicationData` will follow the user.  If you do not wish that behavior, you can use `LocalApplicationData` instead.

Comment: _reasonable guarantee_ ... read as: some IT departments may do weird things and lock these down to very minimal space or no access

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the *isolated storage* classes.

Isolated storage gives you a storage location that is associated with a given *user* and *assembly*; it works in not-fully-trusted environments and it can use roaming to keep the user's data present even on different machines. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.aspx

for details.

Comment: What does *Additionally, data can be isolated by domain* mean?

Comment: @EricJ.: This is a question and answer site. **Ask the question as a question**.

Answer (score 2):

AppData path is probably what you want. This folder in windows XP+ can be referenced with

```
string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Commonly an application creates a sub folder under this to store its data and it doesn't require any special permissions to read/write into.