# how to replace to default path turn into other path?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Default path is `C:\Users\<.YourUser>\AppData\Local\Packages`.
I want to replace it that turn into `C:\Users\<.YourUser>\Desktop` on PC. How can I achieve this?

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c

Comment: Do you want to get path to desktop (as linked in comment above) OR you want to get particular folder and "desktop" is just sample?

Comment: yes. that such Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Comment: GetFolderPath don't support on universal app

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically read that location. You can however ask the user to pick the folder using [`FolderPicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) class. You can set the `SuggestedStartLocation` property to the [`PickerLocationId.Desktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid.aspx) before calling the `PickSingleFolderAsync` method. The user can of course change the location or cancel the operation.