# My goal is to launch a file using vb.net via the click of a button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My goal is to launch a file using this in vb.net via the click of a button..

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("X:\Desktop\Brutal Doom\PLAY ME BRUTAL DOOM!!!.pk3")
```

Which works, however as soon as I move to my laptop or another computer the button can no longer find the file as the drive letter has changed.. is there a way to code this so that it is no longer dependable on the drive letter and only will see `\Brutal Doom\PLAM ME BRUTAL DOOM!!!.pk3` thus working on whatever computer I put the folder on...

Comment: Yay, I am not the only one playing Doom and programming in Visual Basic! -- You could use an `OpenFileDialog` to have the user locate the file the first time the application starts, then just save the path in `My.Settings`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you basically looking for this? [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c)
ie `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Brutal Doom\PLAY ME BRUTAL DOOM!!!.pk3")`