# How can i get a user's path after publishing a .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net

I have just created this .NET program in c# that is supposed to save a pdf file based on user input. the problem is that i want it to be saved on desktop(as for other folders additional permission would be needed and ClickOnce does not accept administrator rights) and for that i would need the user's path. what ways to get it after the user installs the published version exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c)

Comment: "as for other folders additional permission" - no. There is a whole world of folders that compromise the user's profile, not ONLY the desktop. You can write, running as user, into all relevant folders, including locations for application data that are NOT on the desktop. Check the SpecialFolders enumeration and the Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enviornment.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_GetFolderPath_System_Environment_SpecialFolder_) to get the path to a specific folder for the current user:

```
var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Alternatively, another option would be to display a File Save dialog, and that would let the user choose where to save the PDF file. There is a class for [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.8) and [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Like minds...  :)  I like your extra 'file save' too

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current users Desktop folder path by using System.Environment,  use the following to get the Path to the Users Desktop folder.

```
var desktopFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Cheers