# String to do relative path

Tags: c#, path, relative-path

This is my full path:

```
string imagesFolder = "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/Projects/ProjectPacmanGame/Characters/";
```

I tried using ".."
But I get an error I want this whole part to be relative: `C:/Users/danie/Desktop/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634142/how-to-get-a-path-to-the-desktop-for-current-user-in-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path

Comment: @Renat I can't do it with the link you sent