# I have a local db on my dekstop, how do i connect it to my Windows Form on Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: database, visual-studio, winforms, sqlite

I have a local SQLite database called "Welcome.db" which stored users. And i want to create a Wondow Form, which will be adding or removing user form this db.

**This is an image of the Form and the darker grey rectangle is the DataGridView.
The question is how do i fill this DataGridView with objects from my **SQLite** Database.->**
[DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62c6z.png)
**And this is how i have established the connection with the DataBase:**
[Database connection logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J5oh.png)

Comment: See: [How to get a path to the desktop for current user in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/634142/880990) and [SQLite connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) and [SQLite EF Core Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) (or, alternatively [Welcome To Learn Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/)) and [Data binding overview (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview). If you need a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have a DB which stores a user with some parameters.This DB is on my Desktop. I want to take those users and  visualize them in a DataGridView and i want to be able to add new users, delete a user and by finally pressing the save button to save the changes.

Comment: We answer only specific programming questions on SO. [Search elsewhere for a tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+tutorial+winforms+gridview+data+binding)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is this specific enough ?

Comment: We don't do images of code here.  Post it as text.

Comment: You are asking us how to make a whole application. This is very broad.

Comment: Please post your code as text. And provide the detailed description of the code snippet you encountered the problem with.